# RabbitMQ on Android and Java

Tags: java, android, rabbitmq

I am trying to reproduce the [first example](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-java.html) of a Java publisher that can be found in RabbitMQ's main page.

First, I did it in Java and it worked fine. Then, I tried it on Android and here is where the weird part comes.

I have added manually the same jar libraries that I used in my Java program and that are suggested in RabbitMQ's tutorial. That is to say, `amqp-client-5.4.1`, `slf4j-api-1.7.21` and `slf4j-simple-1.7.22` are added in `/libs` directory and then referenced in the `buid.gradle (module:app)` with the commands `implementation files('libs/amqp-client-5.4.1.jar')` and so on.

Then, I have added the required package dependencies in my `MainActivity.java` file without encountering any error. But when adding the piece of code that should publish the data, the different methods of the imported libraries are not found, for instance, `factory` appears as it did not have the method `setHost`.

I attach the code bellow I am currently using.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String QUEUE_NAME = "hello";
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();

    factory.setHost("192.0.0.0"); //Marked as error
    factory.setUsername("test");
    factory.setPassword("test");
    Connection connection;
    Channel channel;
    connection = factory.newConnection();
    channel = connection.createChannel();

    channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
    String message = "Example3";
    channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME, null, message.getBytes());
    System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + message + "'");
    channel.close();
    connection.close();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Any ideas of why this code is working fine on Java but these libraries fails to be correctly imported in Android?

Comment: You don't normally run code outside of lifecycle methods, try to do that in onCreate and perhaps as an async task.

Comment: those libraries are also available on `mavenCentral()` eg.: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.rabbitmq/amqp-client/5.4.2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In java you cannot have code outside of a method. All what you can do is initializing the class members. IMHO it's not a jar import problem.

Try this:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String QUEUE_NAME = "hello";
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        try {
            factory.setHost("192.0.0.0");
            factory.setUsername("test");
            factory.setPassword("test");
            Connection connection;
            Channel channel;
            connection = factory.newConnection();
            channel = connection.createChannel();

            channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
            String message = "Example3";
            channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME, null, message.getBytes());
            System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + message + "'");
            channel.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (IOException | TimeoutException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Rabbitmq problem", e);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Coming back to your original concern, I don't see any reason why you manually download all you dependencies rather than using built-in gradle dependency management.

If you update the dependencies section in the `build.gradle` file, the required dependencies will be automatically downloaded. It's much more easier to add/remove/upgrade dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.rabbitmq', name: 'amqp-client', version: '5.4.1'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.21'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-simple', version: '1.7.21'
}
```